# Page support for Telerik Report Table based layout

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I am using a Telerik Report Control and it solved lots of Technical problems while dealing with complex report data.
However after some time we got one major issue related to layout and alignments of the data.
The textboxes were getting miss aligned when there is a huge data in some fields which was looking quite messy in the web browser.

After release of Q3 2012, we decided to go with the Table based layout provided by telerik and we hope it will solve our problem for sure.

Ref:  http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/table-working-with-table-cross-table-list-items.html

While working with the trial version of the Q3 we assumed that Table based layout will solve the issue and we will be able to get a well aligned data from the Telerik Report in browser. But here we got another issue related to paging.
As the Table renders all records on the one page and doesn't presents the data with multiple pages irrespective of row count.
I set all Page Settings properly for the report but still not getting the expected results.
It seems telerik renders paging on the basis of repeated details section in it but in my case i have added a Table Control on the details Section it self and have assigned Datasource property of Table control.
Can anybody suggest how to make it to display data page wise :) Or how to get rid of this Miss alignment issue in the report viewer?

Also is there any way we can have command over rendering HTML for report fields? So it will be easy to customize the rendered output and add some Html in it?

Please have a look to following screen shots related to this issue

http://www.telerik.com/ClientsFiles/1feff8ee-5f4a-4f29-8993-9f1a176d4027_table-based-Trial.jpg : New version report rendering single page for 100+ records

Please Help,

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This is due to [Interactive View](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/report-viewers-interactive-print-view.html) soft paging mechanism, that is optimized for screen-based viewing. In other words, you could have a two-page long table which to appear in a single continuous form on the client with a vertical scroll bar (logical layout); when printed, the table will print on two separate sheets of paper (print layout). You can force print preview with the viewer ViewMode property set to [PrintPreview](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/t_telerik_reportviewer_silverlight_viewmode.html)

About using the detail section for table layout, you can set all the textbox docking properties to left. This will help you in keeping all the textboxes height the same.